# Redirect text into a script that typically accepts file redirects

Tags: bash, file, redirect

We have a custom script that we can run by redirecting a temporary file to that script...

```
i.e. 
Step 1
   BASH#echo 'commands' > file    
Step 2
   BASH#script < file
```

Is there a way to simplify the process to only one step... and directly send the commands to the script without the use of the temporary file?

I have attempted to do the following:

```
BASH# script < echo 'commands'
BASH# script < 'commands'
BASH# script < "commands"
```

But I always get a message that it cannot find the file specified...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Well, it depends on what your `script` is doing.Untill then it hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just

```
echo 'commands' | script
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a here-document:

```
script <<END_COMMANDS
commands
END_COMMANDS
```

Or if you only need to send one line (and are using bash):

```
script <<<"command"
```